Sum a column and group it, then divide by a field in another table
I have two tables, one that looks like this:

The other has the countries' populations:

I would like to sum up the revenue by country (I know how to do this part, e.g Select Sum(Revenue), Country from COMPANIES GROUP BY Country;)
and then divide it by the population from the other table to get per capital revenue , so the final result should be


If you have this set: sql_mode=only_full_group_by
Then it will need to be like this:
SELECT companies.country, 
       round(sum(revenue) / country.population, 2) as RevPerCap  
FROM companies
join country on country.name = companies.country  
group by companies.country, country.population


Did the trick , thanks!

That will be enough to get what you need (make sure that the Revenue column is not only an integer).
SELECT sumRev/p.Population, q.Country
FROM (SELECT SUM(Revenue) sumRev, Country FROM COMPANIES GROUP BY Country) q
JOIN Population p ON q.Country = p.Country

